# How to protect all my passwords saved in Google if I lost a phone?

Tags: security, password

I save many passwords in Chrome. I used Chrome in my laptop and my android phone. If I lose my phone, how I can protect my passwords?

Comment: If you had Android Device Manager enabled on your phone, you could simply log in online to the device manager and lock your phone: https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

Comment: If I lose my laptop? How I can protect my password in laptop?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/512470/379821 For PC

Answer (score 2):

As Rexford commented, you should install and configure [Android Device Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm) on your device so that you can [remotely lock it out](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager).

You should also use [full-device encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/), so that the passwords cannot be retrieved via physical access.

Finally, if your device's Chrome is set up to sync passwords, you should sign into that account on Chrome for PC and clear all of the saved passwords so that they will be removed the next time the device syncs:

[image: screenshot 1]

---

[image: screenshot 2]